# Pass data from partial view to controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, html-helper

I have a strongly-typed partial view which displays output in a list format. I want to insert data from partial view in DB. I am struggling with looping through rows in partial view and sending them to controller action to be inserted in DB. Here is what i have so far

Partial:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Student.Models.vwStudent>>" %>

<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Student ID
            </th>           
            <th>
                Past Due Amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Past Due Days
            </th>            
        </tr>

        <% if (Model != null)
           foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBox("StudentID",item.StudentID) %>
            </td>

            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBox("PastDueAmount",item.PastDueAmount) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBox("PastDueDays",item.PastDueDays) %>
            </td>            
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>
```

Here is how I access above partial in master:

```
<div>
<% using(Html.BeginForm("SaveStudentInvoice", "StudentInvoice")) %>
<% { %>
<div>
<% Html.RenderPartial("DisplayStudentInvoiceList"); %>
</div>
<% } %>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult SaveStudentInvoice(IEnumerable<Student.Models.vwStudent> students)
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();

foreach(Student.Models.vwStudent student in students){

        Invoice Inv = new Invoice();
        {
            Inv.StudentID= student.StudentID;
            Inv.PastDueAmount= student.PastDueAmount;   
            Inv.PastDueDays= student.PastDueDays;                 
        };

        db.Invoices.InsertOnSubmit(Inv);
}
        db.SubmitChanges();

        return View();

}
```

In the partial view, there are more than one students listed(2,3,4.. rows). When I click "Save" button I am only able to save the first student listed in Partial (1st row), How can I loop through the remaining students listed in partial to save them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have your bindings wrong, You can start with this sample binding, sorry if there is any typo, I am typing in the editor itself.

**Updated:**

Your Partial:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<SaveStudentInvoice.Models.vwStudent>>" %>

<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Student ID
            </th>           
            <th>
                Past Due Amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Past Due Days
            </th>            
        </tr>

        <% if (Model != null)
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ToList()[i].StudentID) %>
            </td>

            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ToList().ToList()[i].PastDueAmount) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ToList()[i].PastDueDays) %>
            </td>            
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>
```

You Main View:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <div>
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Home")) %>
<% { %>
<div>
<% Html.RenderPartial("Partial",Model); %>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %>

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

You Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<vwStudent> students = new List<vwStudent>();
            students.Add(new vwStudent() { PastDueAmount = 100, PastDueDays = "None", StudentID = "ooooo" });
            students.Add(new vwStudent() { PastDueAmount = 102, PastDueDays = "No", StudentID = "Sollina" });
            return View(students);

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(List<vwStudent> studentModel)
        {

            return View(studentModel);

        }
```

Comment: It is still passing null to my controller action. I have updated my code above

Comment: @user793468 Check this new updates, this builds on my System and should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your inputs names that the MVC binding will recognize as being a collection of objects:

```
       int index = 0;
       foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox(string.Format("Entry[{0}].StudentID", index),
                            item.StudentID) %>
        </td>
        ...
    <% 
           i++;
       } %>
```

Then you can use an `IEnumerable<Student.Models.vwStudent>` as your model type, as tsegay describes.

Comment: It is still passing null to my controller action when I click Submit. I have updated my code above

Comment: @user793468: You don't appear to have made the changes that I recommended in your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform your model binding to a collection.  At the moment it is just binding to single values.

Check out: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx